Get magnitude of CGSize vector in SwiftUI
I'm using DragGesture().onChanged() in SwiftUI to get the drag velocity (a CGSize value), which is a vector.
Is there an easy way to get the magnitude of the CGSize vector without doing the math manually?
Simplified code that I'm using, for context:
Circle()
    .simultaneousGesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged({ tap in
                print(tap.velocity) // the vector I want the magnitude of
            })
    )

Edit: I know the math can be done similar to below, but I suspect that's not the most optimal/performant solution:
let velocityMagnitude: Double = sqrt(pow(tap.velocity.width, 2) + pow(tap.velocity.height, 2))


The tool you want is hypot:
let velocityMagnitude = hypot(tap.velocity.width, tap.velocity.height)

You're correct that your approach is not performant, but only because of the use of pow, which is not a good tool for squaring. It has a lot of overhead compared to a simple multiply.
The better code (if hypot weren't available) would be:
let width = tap.velocity.width
let height = tap.velocity.height
let magnitude = sqrt(width * width + height * height)

The advantage of hypot besides convenience is that it also better handles very large and very small values without overflowing or underflowing. For this kind of work, that's not a big deal, and in fact doing it by hand might be a little faster since it won't do the extra work required to handle extreme values. But I recommend using hypot unless you have a strong reason not to.
